# Weird output for mean calculator

Tags: c, function, calculator, mean

So i'm writing a statistical calculator program, and the first function I started to write was the mean calculator. My issue is that I'm getting extremely large( and wrong) values for the answers.

```
Please Enter a number of inputs
 4
Please enter number 1
 1
Please enter number 2
 2
Please enter number 3
 3
Please enter number 4
 4
Statistical Calculator Menu
(1) Mean
(2) Standard Deviation
(3) Range
(4) Restart/Exit
 1
3940705125981218000000000000000000.000000
```

Here is my source code.

```
const int MAX_DATA=5;
void menu(float numbers[], int amount);
float mean(float numbers[],int amount);

int main() 
{ 
int i, amount;
float numbers[MAX_DATA];

printf("Please Enter a number of inputs \n");
scanf("%d", &amount);
if (amount>MAX_DATA){
              printf("You entered too many numbers");
             }else{  

for (i=1;i<amount+1;i++){
    printf("Please enter number %d\n", i);
    scanf("%f",&numbers[i]);
    }
      menu(numbers,amount);
}  
    getch();
return 0;
}

void menu(float numbers[],int amount)
{
 int input2;
 printf("Statistical Calculator Menu");
 printf("\n(1) Mean\n(2) Standard Deviation\n(3) Range\n(4) Restart/Exit");
 scanf("%d",&input2);
      if(input2==1){
         mean(numbers,amount);
        }

}

float mean(float numbers[],int amount)
{
 int i;
 float sum;
 float average;
 for (i=0; i<amount;i++){
     sum=sum+numbers[i];
     }
     average=sum/amount;
     printf("%f", average);

  return average;   
}
```

Can someone point out the mistake, or explain why this isn't calculating correctly?

Comment: Just the obvious, you're filling the array from 1..n and calculating mean on 0..n-1 with an uninitialized starting value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not initialising `sum` so it is taking whatever garbage value was last in that place on the stack. Change:

```
float sum;
```

To:

```
float sum = 0;
```

Another problem you have is:

```
for(i = 1; i < amount + 1; i++) {
    printf("Please enter number %d\n", i);
    scanf("%f",&numbers[i]);
}
```

Array indexes start at 0, so this should be:

```
for(i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    printf("Please enter number %d\n", i);
    scanf("%f",&numbers[i]);
}
```

Comment: I knew it was going to be some stupid mistake on my part. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what Mike said,

```
for (i=1;i<amount+1;i++)
{
    printf("Please enter number %d\n", i);
    scanf("%f",&numbers[i]);
}

float mean(float numbers[],int amount)
{
   // ..
   for (i=0; i<amount;i++){
    sum=sum+numbers[i];
  }
....
```

From this, you are not filling `numbers[0]`. But in the `mean` calculation, using the value at 0 index.

Comment: When you are using arrays and getting wrong results, first thing to check is how you are filling and using the arrays. Glad it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
float sum;
float average;

for (i=0; i<amount;i++){
     sum=sum+numbers[i];
 }
```

`sum` is not initialized in your program.